# How do I customize the flag zombie on Xbox?

Tags: xbox-360, plants-vs-zombies

How do you customize the flag zombie on Xbox?

Answer (score 7):

**You cannot customize the Flag Zombie in the XBox version of Plants vs. Zombies.**

If you have the Game of the Year edition, any "[Zombatar](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Zombatar)" (custom zombie avatar) you create can be used as the [Flag Zombie](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Flag_Zombie). However, the Game of the Year edition is only available on the PC and Mac platforms.